# Link MySQL with different glibc

Tags: mysql, gcc, glibc

I'm trying to link MySQL with a different glibc that provides e.g. a different pthread implementation and actually thought I got it right a few days ago.
Obviously, I took notes and wanted to reproduce the outcome but I can't get it to link properly, so I must have forgotten a step.

What I did previously was simply to add the flags pointing to my glibc and the default one second to the cmake command.

```
GLIBC_FLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=/path/to/my/glibc/build/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/path/to/my/glibc/build/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

cmake \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install \
    .. \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="$GLIBC_FLAGS" \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="$GLIBC_FLAGS"
```

These flags work when building a simple a test-program but seem not to work with MySQL as `ldd` reports the default glibc for `mysqld`.

```
$ ldd install/bin/mysqld
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff14ffe000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f4f1c9bb000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4f1c7b7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4f1c599000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4f1c295000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4f1bf91000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4f1bd7a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4f1b9b2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4f1cc13000)
```

I also tried to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and changing the linker flags and lib variables in `BUILD/scripts/mysql_config` but none of these seem to work.

**What is necessary to link MySQL against a different glibc?**

Comment: You typically have just one `libc` on your system (2 if you count 32/64 bit). Otherwise you're going to run into all kinds of insane problems that can render your entire userspace unusable.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I need different versions since I test them against each other. I also didn't experience any issues yet as long as the programs are linked properly.

Comment: You're probably going to want to try this at least in a `chroot` jail, or Linux  container.

Comment: Okay but I still need at least two glibcs because the glibc that I'm testing does not provide an implementation of all libc components

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a Kernel-Update, `cmake` apparently ignored the `DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `DCMAKE_C_FLAGS` if they contained a colon-separated list of paths (the options were used when they contained only a single path).

I worked around this by setting the colon-separated pathlist directly in the `CMakeLists.txt` in the MySQL root directory.

Comment: Probably you just have to clear your CMakeCache.txt. That can never happen with a Kernel update!

Answer (score 1):

> ldd reports the default glibc for mysqld.

You should *not* trust `ldd` -- it uses *default* loader -- `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` which is *not* the loader you've compiled your `musqld` to use.

Instead, run your `mysqld` under GDB and do `start` followed by `info shared`. You will likely see that in fact your version of `glibc` is actually loaded.